# How to remove key and object in a CKRecord?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Is there any way to remove an object / key from a `CKRecord`? It somehow acts like an `NSDictionary` but no method available, I believe, to do this task. Unlike in `NSDictionary`, we have `- (void)removeObjectForKey:(KeyType)aKey;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly like the modern syntax of `NS(Mutable)Dictionary`. Just use key subscription syntax and assign `nil`

```
record[@"aKey"] = nil;
```